# Canvasの画像に対して、画像差し替えと場所移動を同時に行いたい

Tags: python, tkinter

画像が変化しながら画像の表示座標を移動する、といった機能があるプログラムを作っているのですが、実行するとたまにラグっているように見えることがあります。

```
import tkinter as tk
class App(object):
    def GUI(self):
        root=tk.Tk()
        root.geometry("600x600")

        self.pic001=tk.PhotoImage(file="picture001.png")
        self.pic002=tk.PhotoImage(file="picture002.png")

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(bg="black", width=796, height=816)
        self.canvas.place(x=0, y=0)

        self.item=self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.pic001, anchor=tk.NW)

        self.canvas.move(self.item,-51,10)
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.item, image = self.pic002)    

        root.mainloop()
app=App()
app.GUI()
```

基本的にはこれで実行しても問題はないのですが
しかしこのコードをもっと正確に言えば、画像表示位置を変えた後に画像を差し替える
という事になります。

そのため、処理が重くなる？と画像表示が思うようにいかず、ラグっているように見えるのだと思います。
この問題を解決するには、画像差し替えと座標移動を同時に行う必要性があると思うのですが、どうすればそれを成すことができるでしょうか？

一応今のところ、プログラムはこんな感じにラグっています
[image: ラグ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

それは「モーフィング」と呼ばれる技術でしょう。
あまりtkinterだけで出来るとは思えないのですが。
むしろ動画作成・編集ソフトの範疇と考えられます。

「動画作成 モーフィング」で検索すると、こんなのが関連しそうです。
PythonならOpenCVとかを使うようにすれば出来るのでは？
[OpenCVで顔のモーフィングを実装する](https://blog.negativemind.com/2016/04/29/morphing-by-opencv/)
[Face Morph Using OpenCV — C++ / Python](https://www.learnopencv.com/face-morph-using-opencv-cpp-python/)

単体のツールならこんなのがあります。
[【AviUtl】モーフィング動画の作り方【アハ体験みたいに画像を徐々に変化させる】](http://aviutl.info/morphing/)
[モーフラッシュ](http://starmediasoft.com/application/morphrush/), [フェイスモーフ](http://starmediasoft.com/application/facemorph/)
[複数画像からモーフィング動画が作成できるフリーソフト 『Sqirlz Morph』](https://pc.mogeringo.com/archives/40557)

---

**更新を受けて**
なるほど、アニメーションとかゲーム的な何かですね。
だとすると、こちら辺りが参考になると思われます。
[Python Tkinter refresh canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21357178/9014308)
[Tkinter canvas animation flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41308900/9014308)
[Moving balls in Tkinter Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25430786/9014308)

たぶん肝となるのは Python Tkinter refresh canvas 回答のこの部分でしょう。
google翻訳したものを載せます。

> キャンバスを更新する唯一の方法は、イベントループで「再描画」イベントを処理することです。 あなたのループでは、イベントループに更新の機会を与えることは決してないので、変更はありません。
>
> 簡単な解決策はself.canvas.update_idletasksを呼び出すことですが、それは単なるハックであり、適切な解決策ではありません。
>
> アニメーションを実行する適切な方法は、イベントループを使用して反復を実行することです。 これを行うには、作業をキュー（この場合はアイドルイベントキュー）に配置します。 afterコマンドでこのキューに物を置くことができます。
>
> あなたがすべきことはあなたのアニメーションの1回の反復を行う関数を書くことです。 基本的に、whileループ内のすべてのものを受け取り、それを関数に移動します。 それから、やるべき仕事がある限り、その関数が継続的に呼び出されるように手配します。 その関数の中にafterを呼び出すことも、アニメーションを制御する別の関数を持つこともできます。

それから、こちらは pygame を使った場合のQ&Aですが、考え方は同等でしょう。
[Flickering dice image when i press my dice button.](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/42rcbf/flickering_dice_image_when_i_press_my_dice_button/)

ご質問のソースがどれだけ実際と合っているか不明ですが、上記を元に考えると、スクリーンやキャンバスの設定・初期化およびメインループ等は別のクラスや関数に移動する。1つのフレームを更新する処理を1つにまとめて、それを定期的に呼び出す。といったあたりでしょうか。

試してみてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！モーフィング・・・ですか、初めて聞いた単語なので調べてみました～！　うーん、なるほど。ちょっと説明不足だったと思いますが、パラパラ漫画の様に画像を切り替えながら座標を更新する、といった機能を作りたいんですよね。確かにモーフィングでも出来るかもしれませんが、画像を、、こう、、一瞬で違う画像に変えたいんですよね。やっぱりtkinter じゃ難しいのかなぁ・・・

Comment: 一応今の状況がもっとわかりやすくなるように、gif画像を載せてみました～

Comment: なるほど・・・わざわざありがとうございます。教えてくださったページを読んで色々試してみます～！

Comment: 教えていただいたサイトを読み、参考にしてみたところ、canvas.after()関数を使う事で無事に問題を解決できました。
具体的に言いますと、座標移動のところをメソッドにまとめて、canvas.after()の処理で呼び出すことで今のところラグを確認できないようになりました。
しかしそこで質問なのですが、このcanvas.after()というのはいったいどういった仕組みになっているのでしょうか？
今自分が思っているイメージは、()内に指定された待機したいフレーム数？が終わった後に関数を呼び出す、と思っているのですが・・・一体どうなのでしょうか？

Comment: 個々のウィジェットに括り付けのTimerコントロールのようなものですね。例えばこんな解説があります。[.after() | tkinter tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/ja/tkinter/example/22870/-after--)